How to reattach wires to a broken connector?
I was replacing a control board on my front loader washer after Helene’s storm surge fried it. Inadvertently broke this 2 wire connector.  Any way to rig it back together or do I have to bite the bullet and replace entire wire harness for $200? Before and after photos below.



Can you access both parts? Do you need to easily be able to take it apart again? Is it still under warranty? If not, consider cutting and replacing with something easily available which can take the voltage and current.

@winny -- "both parts" -- That's a single-part socket. The mate is a PCB edge.

@DavideAndrea Oh! That I could not see from the images. If something rigid is pushed in to the connector, a replacement to something else is problematic. If it's wired, I would replace it with something else if not available on the market.

@DavideAndrea Thank you both! I added pictures. I broke the top part and the red and black wires came off. Was just trying to switch the connects to a new control board and created a new problem

you didn't unlatch the connector before pulling it out

the last picture shows the top view ... please add the bottom view

Thank you @jsotola 42 ! That’s correct. It will seat in the board nicely I just can’t figure out how to keep the wires locked in

@jsotola Thank you for making me aware. I have corrected my answer accordingly.

@winny - Well, after OP posted more pictures, it turns out that you were right and I was wrong. This is an "indirect" RAST 2.5 connector. It does have two parts. My apologies. I corrected my answer.

I have the exact same problem and can't find this connector anywhere for sale. Can I ask the original poster please how they resolved this issue in the end? Sorry if I didn't post this correctly, this is my first time using this forum.

That is a RAST 2.5 card-edge plug (my site). Technically, it's a socket, not a connector (as in, a two-part connector) because its mate is the edge of a PCB. EDIT: After seeing the additional pictures, I see that this is a RAST 2.5 "indirect" connector: it is indeed a two-part connector.
It's an IDC (Insulation Displacement Connector). To repair it:

Remove that piece of black insulation from inside the socket
It looks like someone splayed the blades wide  (shaped like a 'V'); repair them by squeezing them until they are perfectly vertical (shaped like a 'U') (*)
Cut a bit off the end of each wire that came off that socket
Shove the unstripped end of the black wire into the blades of left side of the socket; press in with a flat tool until the blades cut through the insulation
Repeat with the red wire in the right side of the socket
Snap the cover back onto the socket

(*) If that doesn't work, buy a 3-position RAST 2.5 socket or a 2-position RAST 5 socket. Either one will work and brand doesn't matter.

Thank you David and everyone for their input I think my pictures are misleading

@Lisadnyfl this is still a good answer ... the connector lid can probably be used to push the wires into the metal prongs ... use a vise

I was thinking of gorilla taping it down.

My best hope would be to find the part and replace it

@ Lisadnyfl - Here is a manufacturer page but I don't know who sells it. Here is a Digikey page for Molex parts.

@DavideAndrea I think using an IDC blade twice is not reliable, I prefer to solder the wires to the blades in such a case. What do you think about that option?

@Jens I would agree.
